# Insert failed using hive - e

Tags: hive

I tried using hive - e to perform the insert operation,
But it shows:

`FAILED: ParseException line 2:73 cannot recognize input near ',' 'page_name' ',' in column name`

My code just like:

```
insert into t1 (id, `time`, page_name, dd) 
values (123, 1686330000,'aaa','bbb')
```

There is no problem when I executing this SQL statement elsewhere.
Why cannot it be executed when using hive - e alone

Comment: Show us the full command you try to run.